# I just wanted a get api where I can match req.params.id == post._id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

Below is my URL from where I am sending a request with an id which is saved in the database

```
http://localhost:4500/api/v1/get_comments/12345678
```

and this is could be the result also same in the database

```
{
"post_id": "12345678",
"comment": "Top 10 SEO Training Institute"
}
```

And this is my node js code

```
router.get('/get_comments/:id', async (req, res) => {
const comment = await Comment.find({
    $where: function () {
        return (hex_md5(post.id) == req.params.id)
    }
}).exec(function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        let row = {
            status: false,
            status_code: 400,
            message: 'There is some issue'
        }
        res.status(400).send(row);
    } else {
        let row = {
            status: true,
            status_code: 200,
            data: result
        }
        console.log(result);
        res.status(200).send(row)
    }
})
})
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to make get API with query param id which is stored in the database with Mongo DB where clause ??

Answer (score 2):

if post_id key exists in your database then you should simply do :-

```
try{
const comment = await Comment.find({post_id:req.params.id})
//handle response here
} catch(err){
//handle error
}
```

Comment: @HarshvardhanSinghBaghel kindly accept this if it worked for you as it will help me to comment on any post as of now i'm just writing answers directly!